# TextBoxFor: INumber type but with default value = ""

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using Asp.net Core 2.0 and I have the following code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.personalData.sonsNumber, null, new { type = "number", value = "", required = "required", pattern="[0-9]" })
```

What I'm trying to is to use the validate feature that HMTL5 provides. The problem is that my `model.personalData.sonsNumber` is an int and has a number as default value and I need that the default value be set as empty string ("").

I already tried the `value=""` and it is not working.

Can any one tell me how to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type of your property from `int` to nullable int (`int?`)

```
public class PersonalData
{
   [Required]  
   public int? SonsNumber { set;get;}  // I took the freedom to follow CamelCasing :)
}
```

The default value of nullable int will be now `NULL` so the tag helper/html helper will render empty string for that. Default value of `int` type is `0`

Comment: Thank you very much. The `?` works perfect. But you rise me another question: Why you are using the `[Required] ` tag and who this could help me?

Comment: That is for server side modal validation. When the data is posted to the server, the model validation framewok can validate the posted data. The tag helpers will also use this attribute to generate the html5 attributes needed for jquery client side validation. Remember, never trust data coming from client. Always validate on server. If you do not prefer to to leverage the model validation framework , you can simply remove the `Required` attribtue